# Migration help Websphere BPM 8.0.1.3 to 8.5.6 (Redirection rule)

Tags: ibm-bpm

We are migrating from WebSphere BPM 8.0.1.3 to 8.5.6, our plan is to move application by application rather than in a big-bang. The idea would be that when we move an application to the new server, we would create an IHS rule which redirects the related URLs to the new server. That would mean that we keep some applications running on the old server while some are already migrated to the new one.

Is this possible to achieve? Or any other idea alternate to re writing IHS rules? Like make use of WebServer plugins?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think that your current approach is going to work well for you.  I've outlined the various options for IBM BPM upgrades [here](http://www.bp-3.com/blogs/2015/06/bpm-migration-4-approaches-to-success/).  I see several major problems with your approach, all of which come down to the fact that many of the URLs used by IBM BPM contain no details about the context for the request.

The first issue I see IBM uses a portal for a given user's work.  That is all their tasks across the various BPM solutions will appear in the same web UI.  This URL is not different across the Process Applications in the install.  This means that all your users are trying to get their task list by going to a url like - https://mybpmserver/portal.  There isn't a way to understand the process app a given user may be working with in this context, so you don't know who to redirect to the new server.

The second issue is that users are able to work with multiple process apps, so even if the context was known in the above url, you would enter complexities with respect to users working in 2 different process apps unless both have been migrated.

The third issue is that BPM is essentially a state engine.  IBM does not supply a way to "migrate" that state from an old install to a new install on a per Process App (PA) basis, you have to migrate all or none.  Assuming "none" because it feels like you want to follow the drain approach in my article, then you have the problem that the URLs for executing a task do not have the PA context and therefore you won't know which server to direct which task to.  That is for a given PA you will have tasks on both the old server which existed before the upgrade, and the new server which were created after the upgrade, but the URLs for these tasks will look essentially the same.

There are additional issues, but the main one comes down to properly understanding how the run time BPM engines work.  Some of the above issues may be mitigated if you have a separate UI layer for presenting the tasks the users (my company make a portal replacement that can do this) which would permit it to understand the context of the tasks, but if you have this, then you can get the correct behavior in that code and not worry about WAS configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the plugin-cfg.xml merge tool on the two generated plugin-cfg.xml's. That way the WAS Plugin would always know which server had which applications.

Comment: IBM info center says this merge tool can be used for Standalone AppSvrs only. Our environment is ND.

Comment: That is inaccurate, it has been used to merge cells for a very long time.